# A Regular expression as a key in a map

Tags: java, regex

I currently have a class

```
class CompositeKey {

  enum Method { POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE }

  private String url;
  private Method method;

  public CompositeKey(String url, Method method) {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = method;
  }

  public CompositeKey(String url, String method) {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = Method.valueOf(method);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    CompositeKey that = (CompositeKey) o;
    return Objects.equals(url, that.url) &&
            method == that.method;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(url, method);
  }
}
```

It is used as a key in a Map and it works fine. For a URL and a method, I can create a CompositeKey object. With the object, I can find out whether it presents in the map or not. I can retrieve the value of the key object if the map contains the key object.

Now, I need to extend the class so that it will take a regular expression of URL instead of a Url. I can't think an effective approach after the change.

Here is an approach:

For a Url, I need to find whether there is any regular expression match in the map key set or not. If yes, retrieve the value. A problem is the looping for the regular expression match which is O(N) in the time usage.

Any better approach?

Comment: If the patterns are static, using some lexical analyser generator may work. A lexical analyser does basically the same when it recognizes tokens defined by regular expressions. Have a look at ANTLR for example.

Comment: No there isn't. You can't avoid _looping_ the hash keys to match a regular expression. Is that your question ?

Comment: About the best you could do is to create a _static_ string that is a concatenation of the _keys_. Add a delimiter between the keys. Add the delimiter to the regex. Then capture a value within the regex that represents the _key_. Use that capture value as the key to the map to get its _value_. Using this method, you only need to run the regex once on each passed in regex.